# How to reformat an alphanumeric string only for a specific numeric character in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I have

> var = bRes[8] bRes[9] bRes[10] bRes[11] bRes[12]

with

```
variable = re.sub(r'[0-9]+', r'[0\g<0>]', vari)
```

i am getting

> variable = bRes[08] bRes[09] bRes[010] bRes[011] bRes[012]

But I would like to have

variable = bRes[08] bRes[09] bRes[10] bRes[11] bRes[12]

any suggetion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
import re
vari = 'bRes[8] bRes[9] bRes[10] bRes[11] bRes[12]'
print(re.sub(r'\[([0-9]+)]', lambda x: "[{}]".format(x.group(1).zfill(2)), vari))
# => bRes[08] bRes[09] bRes[10] bRes[11] bRes[12]
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/vmnPwq).

The `\[([0-9]+)]` pattern matches `[`, then captures one or more digits into Group 1 and then matches a `]`, the match is passed to the lambda expression as `x`, and the digit substrings stored in Group 1 are post-processed with `.zfill(2)` to pad single digit numbers with a zero.

Comment: thanks. What if I have var = 'bRes8 bRes9 bRes10 bRes11 bRes12' #without brackets


and want to print bRes08 bRes09 bRes10 bRes11 bRes12

Comment: @learnerPy It is much easier then, `re.sub(r'[0-9]+', lambda x: x.group().zfill(2), vari)`, see [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/ZQGozC).

Comment: if i had the option then i would rate you 10/10 for your effort :)